# How are the Ubuntu server preinstalled images resized to fit disk upon first boot?

Tags: boot, server, disk, raspberrypi, resize

could someone please shed some light on what service/script does the resizing of preinstalled images to fit disk after the very first boot?

I will explore the inner workings myself, just need some heads up, to begin with.

I'm specifically looking at the preinstalled Ubuntu server image for Raspberry Pi 4 64 bit.

Thank you in advance, and have a jolly week.

Comment: Depending on how you are installing it (there seems to be many ways), you most likely won't notice it. If you are using dd to write it to the sd card, it will just be expanded when you boot it up.

Comment: @WU-TANG I suspect the OP is looking for the magic that accomplishes the "*will just be expanded when you boot it up*"

Comment: and all the raspberry pi sites call it magic too. The raspi-config script apparently handles the resizing... https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/where-is-the-script-for-raspi-config-stored-in-the-fs-on-raspbian  ...I dont think I've ever ran it

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for getting involved.
raspi-config indeed handles that in Raspberry Pi OS.
Having to implement such a functionality myself, putting together a simple script using 'growpart' and 'resize2fs', managed by a systemd service, was sufficient to get the job done.

Comment: Sharing the script you put together in the answer may be useful to others with the same question. If you do, you will get a +1 from me.

Comment: Simply [edit your answer](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1285386/edit) and copy and paste the `code`. Then format the code as code using the { } icon above the edit window.